# pylutron_caseta help please with Lutron buttons

Tags: python

I'm using the pylutron_caseta python package for use with Lutron devices. At this stage I'm trying to listen for button presses. I'm able to pair with the bridge and get the buttons, but I'm unable to listen for button presses. Here's my code:

```
import asyncio
from pylutron_caseta.smartbridge import Smartbridge
from pylutron_caseta.pairing import async_pair
from os.path import exists


bridgeIp = "192.168.1.40"

async def pair(host: str):
    def _ready():
        print("Press the small black button on the back of the bridge.")

    data = await async_pair(host, _ready)
    with open("caseta-bridge.crt", "w") as cacert:
        cacert.write(data["ca"])
    with open("caseta.crt", "w") as cert:
        cert.write(data["cert"])
    with open("caseta.key", "w") as key:
        key.write(data["key"])
    print(f"Successfully paired with {data['version']}")

async def registerButton(bridge,button_id):
    print("Press the small button on the button device.")

def printThis(x):
    print(x)


async def connect():
    bridge = Smartbridge.create_tls(bridgeIp, "caseta.key", "caseta.crt", "caseta-bridge.crt")
    await bridge.connect()
    buttons = bridge.get_buttons()
    print (buttons)
    for b in buttons:
        print (b)
        loopListen = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.ensure_future(listen(bridge,int(b)))
    loopListen.run_forever()

async def listen(bridge,_buttonID):
    while True:
        bridge.add_button_subscriber(str(_buttonID), printThis)

#Program
if exists("caseta-bridge.crt"):
    print("found pair files")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(connect())
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(pair(bridgeIp))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(connect())
```

I expect that when I press a button on the Lutron Pico remote that I get some sort of response printed. I get nothing printed. I'm guessing I have the "listen" function incorrect, just not sure how.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, can you include the following information: 1. What do you expect to happen? 2. What actually happens? 3. What, if anything, gets printed out?

Comment: 1) I expect that when I press a button on the Lutron Pico remote that I get some sort of response printed. 2 & 3) I get nothing printed.

I'm wondering if I'm not doing the "listen" function incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my Lutron Pico remotes work with a node js module called lutronpro found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lutronpro.

I had to upgrade to the pro lutron controller module to make it work. I would prefer to do this in Python, but at least I could get this to work, and know when a remote button was pressed and from there I could call a python web service to do the rest. I ultimately just made it start up this program on boot on my raspberry pi, and now I use my pico remote to control almost anything in the hous